# Cloud Formation Template errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am beginning to learn Cloud Formation Templates and I am running into issues when I validate the template in AWS Cloud Formation -> Create new stack. I am writing the templates using the CloudFormation plugin in Pycharm. These are a couple of the error messages that I get when validating in CloudFormation:

1/10/2022, 5:41:06 PM - Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 27, column 16)

1/10/2022, 5:40:06 PM - Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 24, column 12)

Below is my simple code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
# Description:
Resources:
  #Create the VPC
  MyCustomVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: '10.3.0.0/16'
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      Tags:
        - key: Name
          value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-application-vpc-acg'
  # Create the Subnets
  PublicSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: '10.3.0.0/24'
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-public-subnet-A'
      VpcId: !Ref MyCustomVPC


  PublicSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: '10.3.1.0/24'
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, !GetAz]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-public-subnet-B'
      VpcId: !Ref MyCustomVPC

  #Create Internet Gateway
  MyInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-Internet-Gateway

  #Attach Internet Gateway to VPC
  MyIGWAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref MyInternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref MyCustomVPC
```

Any help to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I've noticed that all almost your questions got answered yet not a single answer was [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979). Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **many issues**, such as spelling mistakes, missing parentheses, wrong functions. The correct version is:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
# Description:
Resources:
  #Create the VPC
  MyCustomVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: '10.3.0.0/16'
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-application-vpc-acg'
  # Create the Subnets
  PublicSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: '10.3.0.0/24'
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ""]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-public-subnet-A'
      VpcId: !Ref MyCustomVPC


  PublicSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: '10.3.1.0/24'
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, !GetAZs ""]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-public-subnet-B'
      VpcId: !Ref MyCustomVPC

  #Create Internet Gateway
  MyInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-Internet-Gateway'

  #Attach Internet Gateway to VPC
  MyIGWAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref MyInternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref MyCustomVPC
```

Comment: Oh wow @Marcin it worked! I truly appreciate your input! Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @foa771 No problem. Acceptance of the answer would be apprecaited.